# Solutions for the integral $\int\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I have a quick question to do with a specific integral.

Does $$\int\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx$$
equal both

$\ln(e^{2x}-1)-x+c$

and

$\ln(1-e^{2x})-x+c$

If so, why? I know it has to do with natural logarithms but my mind is just blank today.

Comment: Hint: the integrand equals $\cosh x/ \sinh x$.

Comment: $\ln(e^{2x}-1)$ only makes sense when $e^{2x}-1>0$ that is when $x>0$. Likewise $\ln(1-e^{2x})$ only makes sense when $x<0$. So these are both right but in **different** domains.

Answer (score 6):

The indefinite integral actually equals $$\ln \color{red} |e^{2x}-1\color{red} |-x+C=\begin{cases} \ln(e^{2x}-1) -x+C_1,& x\ge 0 \\ \ln(1-e^{2x})-x+C_2, & x\lt 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you. that was what i got nut my textbook gave the other answer so i wasnt sure

Comment: Note that $C$ is only required to be locally constant; it can have different values either side of $x=0$.

Comment: @J.G. of course, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the primitives of $\frac{1}{x}$ are given by $\ln|x|+C$. So you are only missing the absolute value.